# project didn't compile after cloning from github

Tags: android, android-glide

i got this error in the gradle build file in android studio when i try to run a project what i cloned from github 
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. > Could not download artifact 'glide.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0)'    > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/bumptech/glide/glide/3.6.0/glide-3.6.0.jar'.       > peer not authenticated

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the link to that JAR file here in your browser? If it does not work, then there is some sort of firewall/proxy problem, most likely, as the link works fine in my browser.

Comment: Yes I tried and it didn't work I think you are right someone told me that it a problem from my filter thanks a lot